# How to create queue for uploading data in server and get track which has uploaded based on ID

Tags: java, android

I am uploading multiple images on server based on **IDs**. So i want to create a logic for **IDs queue** for tracking which IDs data has uploaded.

For example:

I have 4 ID. A, B, C, D.

Data is uploading using A, B, C, D in loop.

```
for(i = 0; i<4;i++) 
   upload [i] // A, B, C, D
```

suppose server fails upload A and C. then i want to check which ID data has uploaded. My code is below.

```
ProfilePictureMultipartsRequest imageUploadReq = new ProfilePictureMultipartsRequest(RestConstant.UPLOAD_ATTACHMENT_EMAIL,
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){}
    }, new File(documentsModel.getDocumentPath()), documentsModel.getDocument_name(),

    new ProfilePictureMultipartsRequest.ProfilePicUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProfilePicUpdateSuccessfully(String response) {
        // i need to get which ID data has uploaded.
    }}, documentsModel.getID(), documentsModel.getDocument_name());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the state of the upload for each data in objects. Create a model class/template :

```
class DataInfo{
    T data;
    String uploadStatus;
}
```

change the uploadstatus depending on your server upload response and persist the status.